# How to artifact custom files that i added as cache in Gitlab CI?

Tags: android, ios, gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I do have 3 stages in my Gitlab runner. This is for an Android project. In the stage 1 i am taking build and in stage 2 i am just creating dummy text file. In stage 3 I artifact the cached files.

In Job 1 I did cache the apk file and in Job 2 I did cache that dummy text file. The stage creates the caches files in cache/Gitname/ProjectName/cache.zip. Which is outside the project directory. But in stage 3 when I try to artifact I am getting error that I cannot access outside build folder.

```
stages:
  - build
  - output
  - artifact 
  
cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk
    - tmpDir/*.txt


build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    - echo "Build in progress"
    - time
    - echo 'sdk.dir=/Users/Library/Android/sdk' > local.properties
    - cat local.properties
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
    - echo "Build Done"
    - mkdir outputDir/ 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk"

build-test:
  stage: output
  script:
    - rm -rf tmpDir
    - mkdir tmpDir
    - pushd tmpDir
    - pwd
    - echo This is some text > myfile.txt
    - cat myfile.txt  
    - popd   
 
build-artifact:
  stage: artifact
  script:
    - echo "Copying cache" 
    - pwd
  artifacts:
    paths:
    
      - "../../../../../cache/GitUser/cicdtest/main-protected/*.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oversimplified example based on your pipeline on how you can expose the cache as artifact, which works.

```
stages:
  - build
  - output
  - artifact 

cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - dir1/*.txt
    - dir2/*.txt

job A:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mkdir dir1 dir2
    - echo "build" > dir1/hello1.txt

job B:
  stage: output
  script:
    - ls -l
    - mkdir dir2
    - echo "output" > dir2/hello2.txt

job C:
  stage: artifact
  script:
    - ls -l
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dir1
      - dir2
```